# Lua syntax errors when using `Packer` plugin manger with `config=require()` in Neovim

Tags: neovim, lua, packer

I'm using neovim 0.6.0 and my config is written in Lua.

My init.lua file `requires` files such as `mappings` and `plugins`. I use packer to manage plugins, and when calling the packer `use` command I can pass a config file to the command. e.g `use {"kyazdani42/nvim-tree.lua", config = get_config("nvim-tree")}`.

The `get_config()` function simply returns a string `require("path_to_config_file")`. But if I replace `config=get_config("<path>")` with `config=require("<path>")` (and am mindful of how/where lua looks for lua files) then I get an error. The require function can find the lua file fine, but Packer throws this error:

`async.lua:20: Error in coroutine: .. <path to packer.lua>:697: invalid value (boolean) at index 68 in table for 'concat'`

Why is this?

Comment: Well, a string containing code and the actual code are different. One evaluates to a string containing code, and the other evaluates to whatever the semantics of lua’s require are (probably a table in the successful case). Try quoting the replacement as a string

Comment: ah, yes. Good spot.